# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString replace character in web URL

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am able to replace space `" "` character in a URL but when there is a non-english character in it returns wrong URL. Example:

The URL I'm using : `www.mostlifeclub.com/MostWeb/img/gallery2/7göller (2).jpg`

The code I'm using:

```
tempUrl = 
[tempUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

What it returns me is:

```
http://www.mostlifeclub.com/MostWeb/img/gallery2/7göller%20(1).jpg
```

(some chinese characters added in there)

Therefore, I can not show the photo in my photo gallery.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Show all of your code, specifically the code that outputs `tempUrl`. I tried doing the same thing and it works correctly. If you're looking at `tempUrl` in the debugger, sometimes it shows odd characters at the ends of strings, depending on what view you're looking at -- that doesn't necessarily mean anything real.

Comment: stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding solved the problem. thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding method?

```
NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

[string setString:@"http://urlWithStrång€Characters"];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```